# jQuery addClass to element based on attribute value

Tags: jquery

I am stuck with this and need some help.  I know the logical solution for this, but not sure how to translate it to jQuery code (newbie here :)).  Any suggestions or help greatly appreciated!

I need to add a css class (active class), to an element that has a title attribute equal to the value of a variable.  So, let's say my variable currentElement = 'great day'.  There is also an a tag element on the page that has the title attribute of 'great day', such as `<a title='great day' href='#'>`.

With jQuery I want to:  Find a tag in the DOM where currentElement == a tag title and add css class.  So, ideally it should find that a tag and add the css class to it.

I came up with something like this but not working:

```
/* set currentElement var to the src attribute 
   value of an a tag on the page
   this works */
var currentElement = $('#greatLink'] img[src*=' + test + ']').attr('src');

/* now find an a tag on the page that has 
   the same title attribute as var currentElement
   this does not work */
$("a[title ='+currentElement+']").addClass('selectedThumb');
```

Comment: some syntax errors in the example code (*first part*)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just need to change your selector to use double quotes instead of the nested single quotes that you have:

```
$( 'a[ title=' + currentElement + ']' ).addClass( 'selectedThumb' );
```

Just to point out, the value of the attribute in the selector doesn't need to be quoted.  e.g.

```
$( 'a[ title="foo" ]' )
```

is the same as

```
$( 'a[ title=foo ]' )
```

The entire selector itself is just a string.  Whether or not you quote the value *foo* in the sample above is irrelevant to the result.  While it might look more "correct" to quote the value, since it's not necessary I find it easier to just leave it off.  It almost certainly makes it less confusing in the issue such as yours, where you're concatenating literal strings with variable values.

Comment: thanks a lot for your tips and insight on this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[title="' + currentElement + '"]').addClass('selectedThumb');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("a[title ='"+currentElement+"']").addClass('selectedThumb');
```

Notice the extra quotes.

Comment: Wow. Looks like I should refresh before posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[title='+currentElement+']').addClass('yourclass');
```